# Xcode 8 Interface Builder puts erroneous space in class name when linking buttons to IBOutlets

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder

I have a bunch of buttons, labels, text fields, etc. in my app already that are functioning fine with outlets/actions. I've already overcome several types problems with having to manually check they were linked to the IB, not using them before they're loaded etc. as well.

However, now I have a view controller that has a Google Map for the view (*I've* no reason to suspect this is relevant but maybe you do) and a single button that I expect to start hidden and then become shown following an event. I get the error:

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

when I call:

```
myButton.isHidden = true
```

from my viewDidLoad(). I have the outlet up top, but, as the question title states, there's a space in the class name. My view controller is named `MyCoolVC` but the outlet under Referencing Outlets in the Connections Inspector says it's linked to `My CoolVC`. I suspect this is causing the outlets to malfunction.

I thought it might have something to do with setting the view controllers' "view" property to the GMSMapView object, but I commented those lines out and it still crashes before the view appears.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds very familiar to me. Are you overloading `loadView` to set `GoogleMap`? If so, the reason it happens is the view at the moment `xib` or `storyboard` loaded and the view you override are different. If you want to use `GMSMapView` with `xib` or `storyboard`, you have to instantiate the google map view manually instead of using `loadView`.

Comment: Oh wow, interesting...now how the hell would I ever figure that out! Thanks, I'll try this now!

Comment: I don't think I'll ever learn why that space is there, but your answer solved my problem. This underlying principle also proved to be the circumstance of other problems I had afterwards.